# Loop through file and remove several lines with different text

Tags: loops, powershell, foreach, where-clause

I am trying to loop through a file and remove lines that are not needed. The rows in the file have a unique number that does not change. What I have so far does not remove the line in the foreach loop but separately it does.

```
$FSEFiles=get-childitem E:\FSE*.txt

foreach ($file in $FSEFiles)

{

    try

    {
        (Get-Content $file.PSPath) | 
        Foreach-Object  { Where-Object { $_ -notmatch "15987@" } } |
        Foreach-Object  { Where-Object { $_ -notmatch "16422@" } } | 
        #Foreach-Object {Where-Object { $_ -notmatch "17526@"}} | 
        #Foreach-Object {Where-Object { $_ -notmatch "17527@"}} | 
        #Foreach-Object {Where-Object { $_ -notmatch "17528@"}} | 
        #Foreach-Object {Where-Object { $_ -notmatch "17530@"}} | 
        #Foreach-Object {Where-Object { $_ -notmatch "17531@"}} | 
        #Foreach-Object {Where-Object { $_ -notmatch "17532@"}} | 
        Set-Content $file.PSPath

        write-host $file updated
    }
    catch
    {
        write-host Error editing $file
    }
}
```

Did I miss something that will allow this loop to work on each line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are already using regex lets merge all these requirements into one nice regex string

```
$regex = "(15987@|16422@|1752[6-8]@|1753[0-2]@)"

$data = Get-Content $file.PSPath 
$data | Where-Object{$_ -notmatch $regex} | Set-Content $file.PSPath
```

Perhaps something like that would stream line it. Not really tested but should work. What you have might have worked in place but something seems malformed with the combination of `foreach` and `where` ( hence the question ) but it would be redundant to try and address that I would think.

Comment: Perfect! That did exactly what I needed it to do.
Thank you.

Comment: Glad that helped. Please consider marking this an the answer with the checkmark under the votes on the left.